# Request for Hints : Possibilities to log files from a router to a server

Tags: c, logging, ssh, openwrt

here is the situation:

I have written a C program doing some wireless measurements on a WRT54GL Router (OpenWRT White Russian, Busybox 1.00, Dropbear client v0.49). Please note that i can not use a more up to date version of the operating system on the router or install additional packages (just scripts or small programs are allowed).

Up to now, i log my measurements results every 15 minutes from the router to the server via a
`cat localfile | ssh target_address cat ">" remotefile`

which i call from my C program (system()) for every logfile which is created or present at the moment the log starts. What i don't like is, that the system call opens a new shell for every single call, causing some overhead. The good thing is that in this way the data is encrypted and because i do a connection for every file, i can directly get per file feedback from the server, so that i can remove the logs from the router. (Other approaches calling scripts from the router on the server, which then return values for the logging did not work, as the dropbear ssh client does not support this return).

So what i'm asking for: what could be a more elegant way to do so and to reduce this overhead ? By now, i've read a few tutorials about how to use TLS / TCP Sockets (so i can send the data encrypted to the server). Another possibility could be a HTTP PUT or POST, but there i am not sure how i could get feedback for the data being send. So i would just like to hear your oppions and how you guys would try to tackle this.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about log files, this sounds like a job for the [`syslog` protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog).

I am pretty sure OpenWRT supports it out of the box.